# Error in grid.Call(C_convert, x, as.integer(whatfrom), as.integer(whatto), : Viewport has zero dimension(s)

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a volcanoplot but I get this error:

```
Error in grid.Call(C_convert, x, as.integer(whatfrom), as.integer(whatto),  : 
  Viewport has zero dimension(s)
```

I've never had this probelm, the code used to work just fine. It's basically a volcanoplot of cells according to labels. I'm trying to see the difference between two groups.

```
p=c()

for (i in 1:nrow(scores.batch)){
  p[i] = wilcox.test(scores.batch[i,totaldata$Response=='Response'],scores.batch[i,totaldata$Response=='NoResponse'])$p.value
}
p.adj = p.adjust(p,method='fdr') 
lfc = log2(rowMeans(scores.batch[,totaldata$Response=='Response'])/rowMeans(scores.batch[,totaldata$Response=='NoResponse']))
set.seed(42)
DF.2 = data.frame(lfc, p, labels= rownames(scores.batch))
EnhancedVolcano(toptable = DF.2, lab=DF.2$labels, drawConnectors = TRUE,
                x='lfc',y='p',pCutoff = 0.5, FCcutoff = 0.25, ylim = c(0,7.5), xlim = c(-1.5,1.5))
```

What could cause this? I tried restarting R but it didn't help.

Comment: I know this happens sometimes when the viewer window is too small - try increasing its size, perhaps?

Comment: @KaiAragaki Yes it worked. I feel stupid, thanks!!

Comment: It's a bit of a confusing error...I get why you were confused. Also feeling stupid is the name of the game my friend - that's the path to progress we walk.

Comment: I've made my comment an answer so that this can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs when the viewer window is too small - try increasing its size to stop the error.

Answer (score 0):

For my workflow I needed a programmatic solution to this problem. I run this function just before executing the code of the plotting functions that can trigger this error. In most cases it successfully enlarges RStudio's output pane, thus avoiding the error. The user just needs to specify the `height.` and `width.` arguments (in pixels) that are suitable for their screen.

The function does a few things:

1. Detects the dimensions of the Output pane (which includes the plot window).
2. Conditionally increases the Output pane's height to a specific value, if the detected height dimension is less than that value of `height.`.
3. Conditionally increases the Output pane's width to full screen if the detected width dimension is less than the `width.` value.

One goofy aspect of this work-around is that it causes the Output pane to switch to the Viewer window whenever it adjusts the height.

```
enlarge_output_pane <- function(height. = 700, width. = 1300){

  # detect current output pane dimensions
  dim_px <- grDevices::dev.size("px")

  # if detected width is less than 'width.', widen output pane with RStudio's layoutZoomRightColumn command
  if(dim_px[1] < width.){ rstudioapi::executeCommand("layoutZoomRightColumn") }

  # if detected height is less than 'height.', switch to Viewer windom and set height
  if(dim_px[2] < height.){

    viewer <- getOption("viewer")
    viewer("http://localhost:8100", height = height.)

  }

}
```